# Calculate $\int\int_D xy(x^2 + y^2)dx\,dx$ where D is the set that bounded by $1 \le xy \le 2 \text{ and } 5 \le x^2 - y^2 \le 9$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

An exercise from the book that I have a difficults to solve..

> Calculate $\int\int_D xy(x^2 + y^2)dx\,dx$ where D is the set that bounded by $1 \le xy \le 2 \text{ and } 5 \le x^2 - y^2 \le 9$

The answer is $-3$ but it not telling how he got this answer.

Can you please explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let u = xy, and v = x^2 - y^2, then the dxdy = 1/det(A)*dudv with A is the matrix

du/dx     du/dy

dv/dx     dv/dy

which is:

y     x

2x    -2y

So det(A) = -2y^2 - 2x^2 = -2(x^2 + y^2)

Thus the new integrand is : xy(x^2 + y^2)/det(A) = -1/2*u. So the integral equals to:

Int(v = 5 --> v = 9)(Int(u = 1 -> u = 2) of -1/2*u ) dudv = - 3.